# Ruby on Rails 4- Passing params in Simple_form_for when clicking submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, simple-form-for

I have a `simple_form_for` *(I can also use `simple_form` if easiest)* that I want to pass/update 3 params. 1 of them is "user-generated", while 2 others needs to be insert/update in db "automatically".

Here is my current form:

```
= simple_form_for @request do |f|
  = f.collection_select :partner_id, @partners, :id, :full_name,  {prompt: "Select a user"}
  = f.input :successful_ad, checked: true, value: true
  = f.input :status, checked: false, value: 0
  = f.submit "I have excepted"
```

What I am looking for is user can choose a `:partner_id` from `collection_select`, while I need to insert/update `:successful_ad => true` and `:status => false`.

I don't want to use **hidden_field** since it can be manipulated and safest way is to process them in background.

*PS: reason I can't pass these params in edit/update actions is since I have this form in show action and is separated.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, the safest way to always use server side code for it. But you need to know when it has to happen, and this is something that comes from client end.

You can use `after_save` or `after_update`, and can do the work there. But not every `save` or `update` action would need this; only a few may need this. So you need to have a hidden field in your form, and but you can encrypt the content of that, and then, on server side, you can do the certain task in your callback if you received that encrypted key.

An end user would always have the power to change the contents of hidden field, so now it's up to you to use an encrypted key, and a column name that a user wouldn't be able to break through.

Edit: for what you asked, you can do following:

```
= f.input :status, :input_html => { :checked => false, value: 'Your desired value'}
```

Comment: I am not familier how to make the hidden_field encrypted. But in simple_form_for, how can i make the checkbox uncheck and check?

Comment: What do you mean by **how can i make the checkbox uncheck and check?**

Comment: I want to use use hidden:field now and the **:status**  filed is already **true** and I want it to be **false** and **: successful_ad** is **null** and I want it to be **true**, I have tried `checked: true` & `checked: false`, but no luck...

Comment: Please show me your code by editing your question, and putting it there.